# Wrong documentation for Mega2560 SPI Pins?

Tags: arduino-mega, spi

This page https://store.arduino.cc/usa/mega-2560-r3 contains an image under the Documentation section which shows digital pins 10 to 13 with labels SS, MOSI, MISO, and SCK.

**EDIT:** The documentation page has since been updated with the correct pin assignment as discussed below. The image has been removed to stop it from showing up in "mega SPI pinout" searches and continuing to spread wrong information.

However, this page says that those are at pins 50 to 53 https://www.arduino.cc/en/reference/SPI.

[image: table from SPI page]

Which page is correct?

Comment: check the schematic ... the top picture is incorrect ... PB4 to PB7 are not SPI pins  ... ATmega2560 datasheet confirms that PB0 to PB3 are SPI pins ... these are pins 50 to 53 on the Arduino board

Comment: https://store.arduino.cc/store-support

Comment: I have asked Arduino store tech support to check on it - "        Your inquiry was submitted and will be responded to as soon as possible. Thank you for contacting us."

Comment: Got reply from Arduino Store as well. " it is being taken care"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The image is incorrect, unfortunately.

The SPI pins are below:

```
PB0 - #SS
PB1 - SCK
PB2 - MOSI
PB3 - MISO
```

[image]

[image]

[image]